# Failed to generate quickstart.xml while deploying on App Engine Standard

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, java-8

I have been trying till my wits end since past 3 days about this issue and probably tried every solution on SO and Git forums.

In google app engine,
The app runs perfectly on local server but while deploying,
the following error is shown.

> Reading application configuration data...
>   ********************************* Configuration Warning : / XML elements and --application/--version
>   should not be specified when staging
>
> The following parameters will be scrubbed from app.yaml application :
>   shsDemo version : 1.1
>
> Future versions of staging will fail if application or version is
>   specified.
>
> ---
>
> Beginning interaction for module default... 0% Scanning for jsp files.
>   0% Compiling jsp files. Feb 01, 2018 8:10:47 PM
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars INFO: At least one JAR
>   was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for
>   this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs
>   were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time. Feb 01, 2018 8:10:48 PM
>   org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile INFO: Built File: /feedback.jsp
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.QuickStartGenerator
>   Error while executing: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -cp
>   /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/jetty-util-9.3.18.v20170406.jar:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/jetty-deploy-9.3.18.v20170406.jar:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/jetty-http-9.3.18.v20170406.jar:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/jetty-proxy-9.3.18.v20170406.jar:/usr/lib/google-cloud-
>   . . . similiar such logs . . . . Unable to stage app: Failed to
>   generate quickstart-web.xml. Please see the logs
>   [/tmp/appcfg5433316199131614644.log] for further information.

In logs,

> Unable to stage:
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to generate quickstart-web.xml.
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createQuickstartWebXml(Application.java:1806)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.populateStagingDirectory(Application.java:999)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:872)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplication(AppAdminImpl.java:539)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplicationWithDefaultResourceLimits(AppAdminImpl.java:492)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$StagingAction.execute(AppCfg.java:2529)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:390)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.(AppCfg.java:213)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.(AppCfg.java:119)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:115)
>       com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to stage app: Failed to generate quickstart-web.xml.
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplication(AppAdminImpl.java:543)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplicationWithDefaultResourceLimits(AppAdminImpl.java:492)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$StagingAction.execute(AppCfg.java:2529)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:390)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.(AppCfg.java:213)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.(AppCfg.java:119)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:115)
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to generate quickstart-web.xml.
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createQuickstartWebXml(Application.java:1806)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.populateStagingDirectory(Application.java:999)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:872)
>         at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.stageApplication(AppAdminImpl.java:539)
>         ... 6 more

JDK: oracle 8.
Please help me find the issue and deploy the project on App Engine.
I have deployed the same project before.

Comment: Which is your exact deployment command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using GCloud SDK version 187.0.0?

I had the same issue with this version of the SDK, even got the same error when running the Tutorial project from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart

I uninstalled the SDK and installed the prior version (186.0.0) and now everything is working fine again. Maybe it can solve the issue for you as well.

Old versions are available for download here:

https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/cloud-sdk-release?authuser=0&prefix=google-cloud-sdk-186

Comment: Thankyou for your insight. However I am unable to update or install v 186.0.0.   All I get is the list of supported modules.

Comment: The value '186.0.0' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources

Comment: I found the same solution in January. Currently, gcloud components version 188.0.1 doesn't work either

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. For developers that use Google Cloud Shell to build and deploy on App Engine, you can change gcloud sdk versions by:

```html
sudo gcloud components update --version 186.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to revert to version 186.0.0-0 by removing the old version. Try installing old version using apt. It will only work if you have installed google cloud sdk as a .deb package on debian/ubuntu.

```
apt-get install google-cloud-sdk=186.0.0-0 google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java=186.0.0-0
```

And deployment also works after reverting to old version.

I have also opened an issue on google's issue tracker for cloud sdk
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72808542

Comment: Yes, the main difference was, writing 186.0.0-0  and not 186.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Temporary work around.

Today, the gcloud tool is at version 188.0.1 and the mvn deployments still don't work. Though, I found a workaround.

After downloading the GAE sdk:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download

I copied the missing jar to the location that was mentioned:

```
cp -r  appengine-java-sdk-1.9.62/lib/tools/quickstart [TO YOUR SDK PATH]google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/lib/tools/
```

Subsequently, the mvn appengine:stage and mvn appengine:deploy worked as expected.

Reference: [basis for work around](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72808542#comment4)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with version 187, I solved the problem by downgrading to version 186.

- I ran this 2 commands :

  ```
  apt-get install google-cloud-sdk=186.0.0-0 google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java=186.0.0-0

  gcloud components update --version 186.0.0
  ```